# Error:Expression expected

Tags: android, android-intent, start-activity

```
Intent danielIntent = new Intent(Broadcast.this, Broadcasting.class);
 danielIntent.putExtra(String,"Free Loop");
 startActivity(danielIntent);
```

There is an error said expression expected,I don`t what should do next.

Comment: Change `danielIntent.putExtra(String,"Free Loop");` to `danielIntent.putExtra("your_key","Free Loop");`

Comment: You can't use reserved keyword as an arguments. You've used `String` as an parameter.

Comment: Sorry, it sounds bad and unhelpful, but the answer is: "try to learn Java" (you are unlikely to benefit from any other question and will hit a next stumbling block immediately).

Answer (score 1):

```
danielIntent.putExtra("","Free Loop"); // 1st Parameter is KEY
```

1st Parameter must be within **" "**

You should read **[Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)** at First .

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the data in form of **key-value pair** ("yourkey","value")

```
Intent danielIntent = new Intent(Broadcast.this, Broadcasting.class);
danielIntent.putExtra("keyvalue","Free Loop");
startActivity(danielIntent);
```